Ansible Lint not finding community.general included with Homebrew-installed Ansible
I am having an issue with Ansible Lint not finding community.general modules:
> ansible-lint <redacted>.yml
WARNING  Listing 1 violation(s) that are fatal
syntax-check[unknown-module]: couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.locale_gen'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
<readacted>.yml:16:3

This action is:
- name: Set locale
  community.general.locale_gen:
    name: en_US.UTF-8

I'm on macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 and I've installed Ansible via Homebrew (version details at the end). From what I can tell, this includes many of the Community modules without having to install them via Ansible Galaxy:
> ansible-galaxy collection list | grep community.general
community.general                        8.6.0

So the playbook runs just fine, but ansilbe-lint cannot find the module.

I did notice this at the top of ansible-galaxy collection list:
# /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.5.1/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible_collections
Collection                               Version
---------------------------------------- -------

If I set ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATH to that /opt/homebrew/.../ansible_collections path, then it works. But it seems like I shouldn't have to do that? If ansible-playbook can find it, why can't ansible-lint? How can I get ansible-lint to automatically look in the builtin collection path?

Version info:
> ansible --version
ansible [core 2.16.6]
  config file = /Users/dave/work/ansible/dribin-infra/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/dave/work/ansible/dribin-infra/library']
  ansible python module location = /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.5.1/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/dave/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /opt/homebrew/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.12.3 (main, Apr  9 2024, 08:09:14) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)] (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.5.1/libexec/bin/python)
  jinja version = 3.1.3
  libyaml = True

==> ansible: stable 9.5.1 (bottled), HEAD
Automate deployment, configuration, and upgrading
https://www.ansible.com/
Installed
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.5.1 (31,927 files, 365.5MB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2024-04-26 at 23:40:10
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/a/ansible.rb
...


UPDATE 2024-05-22: This is due to interaction between the COLLECTIONS_SCAN_SYS_PATH Ansible setting and the fact that Homebrew installs Python apps into their own virtual environments.
When COLLECTIONS_SCAN_SYS_PATH is set to true, which is the default, Ansible will look in sys.path for installed collections.  However, when Homebrew insalls Python apps, it will typically install them into their own virtual environment:

Applications must be installed into a Python virtual environment rooted in libexec. This prevents the app’s Python modules from contaminating the system site-packages and vice versa.

So when installing ansible and ansible-lint via Homebrew, each get their own isolated vesion of sys.path, by being in their own venv. This means ansible and ansible-playbook can find the collections, but ansible-lint cannot find them.
One possible work around would be to set collections_scan_sys_path = false in ansible.cfg, and then explicitly install all dependent community collections.
While this sounds more robust, and I may eventually try this, the work around I used is to install both with pipx, and careful use of pipx inject.
First, I tried installing ansible and ansible-lint separately via pipx, instead of Homebrew:
pipx install --include-deps ansible
pipx install ansible-lint

Ansible required injecting passlib so that the password_hash filter works:
pipx inject ansible passlib

Unfortunatley, this still failed in the same way that the Homebrew installations did, because they are in separate isolated virtual environments.
HOWEVER, instead of installing ansible-lint separately in pipx, if it, too, was injected into the ansible virtual environment, then it works:
pipx inject --include-apps ansible ansible-lint

Note that --include-apps is required here so that ansible-lint is symlinked to the bin/ directory.
> pipx list
   ...
   package ansible 9.5.1, installed using Python 3.12.3
    - ansible
    - ansible-community
    - ansible-config
    - ansible-connection
    - ansible-console
    - ansible-doc
    - ansible-galaxy
    - ansible-inventory
    - ansible-lint
    - ansible-playbook
    - ansible-pull
    - ansible-test
    - ansible-vault


Thanks Dave! In my case, the command was pipx inject --include-apps ansible-lint ansible then it worked just fine!
